# Code snippet editor auto adds a closing slash to <link> tags

Tags: support, bug, stack-snippets

When using the code snippet editor, and you want to add an external library by clicking on that button, it automatically adds a closing slash when it inserts a `<link>` tag. However, in HTML, a closing slash is not specified (though it's allowed for backward compatibility reasons only).

Note that the `<link>` tag is also a [void element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/syntax.html#void-elements) Void elements are those which contain no content, which the link element is. So

> there may be a single U+002F SOLIDUS character (/)
>   https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/syntax.html#start-tags

However

> This character has no effect

Stack Overflow editors should follow [the HTML standard for the link tag](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-link-element) where you will see no closing slash is specified by the wording and is not shown by any example. Closing slashes for HTML have never been specified in any HTML spec.

Comment: Is the closing / not allowed or is it optional? If it's optional, I see no problem with it.

Comment: @BDL It's not optional but it is allowed. It has no meaning, it does nothing and browsers are instructed to ignore it. Again, it is not specified to be used in the HTML standard.

Comment: It was specified by the XHTML spec. And, yes, technically, XHTML was not HTML, but this is a really pedantic bug. Considering most questions being asked on this site barely get the difference between `head` and `header`, this is pretty low priority. First we should look at updating the console with canon's latest code, then do something about multi-file setups, then something about faking ajax, then allow the use of babel/TypeScript/SASS/LESS/etc., then a switch for auto-tidy on post. Then maybe we can talk about removing a character that does nothing when present in code.

Comment: @HereticMonkey None of that has anything to do with my post. A discrepancy is a discrepancy no matter the priority.

Comment: On the other hand, this is a fix which literally requires a trivial *one-character* change. `var link = '<link href="' + url + '" rel="stylesheet"/>';` can be changed to `var link = '<link href="' + url + '" rel="stylesheet">';`, done, no other consideration necessary, which is much less than most bugs require

Comment: For html.spec.whatwg.org: *"[Is this HTML5? ... In short: Yes. ... the term "HTML5" is widely used as a buzzword to refer to modern web technologies, many of which (though by no means all) are developed at the WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#is-this-html5?)"* ([WHATWG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHATWG) = *Web Hypertext Application Technology Working Group*)

Comment: What does [HTML validation](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&doc=https%3A%2F%2Fpmortensen.eu%2Fworld%2FEditOverflow.php) say? (Yeah, it is [WordPress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress) interference - [a different version](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&doc=https%3A%2F%2Fpmortensen.eu%2Fworld%2FEditOverflow.php%3FLookUpTerm=don%27t%26OverflowStyle%3DNative) exists.)